# Overwrite rewrite-rule of htaccess in parent folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, directory, parent

I have a .htaccess with a rewrite-rule which just rewrites all in a parent-folder (/). Now I want to install Wordpress in a child-folder (/blog/), but this doesn't work, because the parent folder rewrites all to another file.

Is there any way to exclude the .htaccess of the parent folder from the htacces in /blog/ (which means withoug chaning the .htaccess in /)?

I know I could change the .htaccess in /, but this would cause some a lot of other problems...

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following line to the top of the htaccess in the root. That should prevent it from applying rules beneath it if the url starts with `/blog/`

```
RewriteRule ^blog/ - [L]
```