# Parent htaccess override subfolder htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I have a Zend aplication that uses a hatccess and redirects everything to index.php, but now i need to use a password protect folder in one of the subfolder, but when i tried to acess the subfolder keep giving me 404 error.

here the zend htaccess in the public_html folder:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule !\.(js|txt|ico|gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|css|swf|pdf|xml|XML|eot|svg|ttf|woff)$   index.php
 SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"
```

here the subfolder htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine off
AuthType Basic
AuthName "*folder*"
AuthUserFile "/home/*user*/.htpasswds/public_html/*folder*/passwd"
require valid-user
```

i tried to add `RewriteRule ^blog/ - [L]`to the public_html folder as i see in:
[Overwrite rewrite-rule of htaccess in parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447432/overwrite-rewrite-rule-of-htaccess-in-parent-folder)

but it didnt work. what is weird is that if i take the password part of the subfolder htaccess, the "rewriteEngine off" work and i got a list of the files in that folder.

Obs: the server is a apache 2.2.25, so rewriteOptions InheritBefore is not a options

Obs2: the *folder* and *user* is not like that on the actual htaccess that was just to hide the names.

Obs3: im a noob in server configurations :)

Answer (score 0):

This usually works for me. Paste code in the parent htacesss underneath your RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(blog)($|/) - [PT,L]
```

Comment: it didnt work :(
im starting to think that the server has some configuration that i dont know about.

Comment: I dont know what kind of server your application is running on. But this can be an override problem. When you are using apache with vhosts. It is possible to set AllowOverride All. See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Ow your server version is listed in the question. Sorry my bad. Can you check if AllowOverride is set to all. If not. Set is to All and restart apache :)

Comment: i dont have how to check if allowOverride is on or not.